# iOS push notifications troubleshooting (RoR)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I have to deal with some legacy code. It uses pushmeup and sidekiq gems to send push notifications to mobile devices. Push notifications for Android work just fine. But for some reason I have problems with iOS. I can make them work locally, but I can't make them work on a server. Certificate is the same. There are no errors in sidekiq logs.

```
class PushWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(device, params)

        APNS.host = 'gateway.push.apple.com'
        APNS.pem  = Rails.root.join('certificates/mes_push_prod.pem')
        APNS.port = 2195
        APNS.pass = '123'
        APNS.send_notification(params['to'], alert: params['alert'], badge:  params['badge'], sound: 'default')
        puts APNS.feedback

  end
end
```

Also `puts APNS.feedback` returns only dead tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that I had too many symbols in json, which was sent to apple push notification server. After shortening the message it started to work just fine.